# R integrate: view vector argument

Tags: r, integrate

Is there a way to see the vector R assigns with the integrate function to evaluate the integrand? That is, integrate is of the form:

integrate(f, lower, upper, ...)

where function f must act on some vector, say x. That is,

f <- function(x, ...) { }

When using integrate on function f, is there a way to view the vector x which R assigns to evaluate the integrand?

To make this question more concrete, I will present a specific instance of this problem below. When using the integrate function in R, I get the following warning message:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In mean_v_tmp - func_mu_grid[ifelse(low == 0, NA, low)] : 
        longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Although this is a straightforward warning message that the two vectors are not of the same (or proper) length, the issue here actually has to do with the integrate function.

The warning is best understood in context, so the relevant code is pasted here, and the discussion is continued below:

```
    #Define parameters.
    curr_mean_v = -14; curr_sigma_v= 0.1; sigma_epsilon= 2; 
    mu_grid = seq(-14, 18, by=0.5); 
    sigma_grid = seq(0.01, 4, by=0.2);
    STATES_t <- expand.grid(mu_grid, sigma_grid, 2);
    V = rep(0.01, 1300);

    #Stop on warnings.
    options(warn=2)

    #Define function for the integrand when calculating the expected value to go. 
    integrandFunc_V <- function(x, func_mean_v, func_sigma_v, func_sigma_epsilon, func_V, func_STATES, func_mu_grid, func_sigma_grid) {

        #Update the values of mean_v and sigma_v.
        mean_v_tmp <- (func_mean_v/func_sigma_v^2 + x/func_sigma_epsilon^2) / (1/func_sigma_v^2 + 1/func_sigma_epsilon^2);
        sigma_v_tmp <- 1/(1/func_sigma_v^2 + 1/func_sigma_epsilon^2);

        #Round mean_v_tmp to values on mean_grid. 
        low <- findInterval(mean_v_tmp, func_mu_grid)   #find index of number just below
        high <- low + 1 #find the corresponding index just above
        #Find the absolute difference between the grid number above and below.
        low.diff <- mean_v_tmp-func_mu_grid[ifelse(low==0,NA,low)]
        high.diff <- func_mu_grid[ifelse(high==0,NA,high)]-mean_v_tmp
        mins <- pmin(low.diff,high.diff,na.rm=T)    #find the minimum difference
        pick <- ifelse(!is.na(low.diff) & mins==low.diff, low, high)
        mean_v_tmp <- func_mu_grid[pick]

        #Round sigma_v_tmp to values on sigma_grid.
        low <- findInterval(sigma_v_tmp, func_sigma_grid)   #find index of number just below
        high <- low + 1 #find the corresponding index just above
        #Find the absolute difference between the grid number above and below.
        low.diff <- sigma_v_tmp-func_sigma_grid[ifelse(low==0,NA,low)]
        high.diff <- func_sigma_grid[ifelse(high==0,NA,high)]-sigma_v_tmp
        mins <- pmin(low.diff,high.diff,na.rm=T)    #find the minimum difference
        pick <- ifelse(!is.na(low.diff) & mins==low.diff, low, high)
        sigma_v_tmp <- func_sigma_grid[pick]

        #Collect the value function values associated with mean_v_tmp and sigma_v_tmp. 
        ind_vec <- rep(NA,length(x));
        for (i in 1:length(x)) {
            ind_vec[i] <- intersect(which(abs(func_STATES[,1] - mean_v_tmp[i]) < .0001), which(abs(func_STATES[,2] - sigma_v_tmp) < .0001));    
        } #end i for loop
        Val_tmp <- func_V[ind_vec];
        f <- dnorm(x, func_mean_v, sqrt(func_sigma_v^2 + func_sigma_epsilon^2));
        output <- Val_tmp * f;
        output
    }

    #Integrate the function. 
    integrate(integrandFunc_V, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, subdivisions=2000, rel.tol= .Machine$double.eps^0.15, func_mean_v= curr_mean_v, func_sigma_v= curr_sigma_v, func_sigma_epsilon= sigma_epsilon, func_V = V, func_STATES = STATES_t, func_mu_grid = mu_grid, func_sigma_grid = sigma_grid)
```

My integrandFunc_V function takes a vector x and acts on it, preparing the integrand for the integrate function. Is there a way to print and see this vector x that the integrate function uses to evaluate the integrand?

If I create my own such x vector and run the code step by step without the integrate function, the warning does not arise and the vectors are all of the same length. For example, the following calculates low.diff without incident:

```
    #Define parameters.
    x <- c(-.Machine$double.xmax, -10^10, 0, 10^10,.Machine$double.xmax);
    func_mean_v = -14; func_sigma_v= 0.1; func_sigma_epsilon= 2; 
    func_mu_grid = seq(-14, 18, by=0.5); 
    func_sigma_grid = seq(0.01, 4, by=0.2);

    #Update the values of mean_v and sigma_v.
    mean_v_tmp <- (func_mean_v/func_sigma_v^2 + x/func_sigma_epsilon^2) / (1/func_sigma_v^2 + 1/func_sigma_epsilon^2);
    sigma_v_tmp <- 1/(1/func_sigma_v^2 + 1/func_sigma_epsilon^2);

    #Round mean_v_tmp to values on mean_grid. 
    low <- findInterval(mean_v_tmp, func_mu_grid)   #find index of number just below
    high <- low + 1 #find the corresponding index just above            #Find the absolute difference between the grid number above and below.
    low.diff <- mean_v_tmp-func_mu_grid[ifelse(low==0,NA,low)]
```

Hence, there must be some issue with my code and the x vector the R integrate function uses. Is there a way to view this vector?

Lastly, I will note that, if V = rep(0,1300), then the warning messages do not appear and the code works fine. However, if V is nonzero, the above issue arises. This is especially odd, since V is not required to calculate low.diff, which is where the warning message arises.

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a *minimal* reproducible example. If you want to view the vector `x`, you can just print it at the beginning of the function. Or you can set `options(error=recover)` to enter a debugger on error. Your problem is that at some point all the `low` values are 0 and when you do `func_mu_grid[ifelse(low==0,NA,low)]` with all `NA`s you get something that's `length(func_mu_grid)` not `length(low)` as you were expecting which triggers the warning.

Comment: The first part of your question asks how the R function `integrate` constructs its 'x' and for that you will need to look at the source code. An integer (32 bits) is passed to `wk <- .External(C_call_dqags, ff, rho = environment(), 
            as.double(lower), as.double(upper), as.double(abs.tol), 
            as.double(rel.tol), limit = limit)`. So it's done in C and you would need to track it down in the 'stats' package. The help page refers you to " Quadpack: a Subroutine Package for Automatic Integration".

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you-- that seems to be the heart of the issue. For what it's worth, I had set options(error=recover), but in fact print(x) was more directly useful to see this. I believe addressing this fixes my problem.